# getRemoteStreams from webRTC peerConnection undefined in safari or mobile IOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc

I was build video call App using webRTC. The app was running smoothly until I tried using safari browser on mac and Chrome browser on Mobile IOS. The error was occur when I get the remote/local stream for my Video Tag sources. The error looks like this :

```
TypeError: e.getRemoteStreams is not a function. (In 'e.getRemoteStreams()', 'e.getRemoteStreams' is undefined)
```

I tried in chrome dekstop was work perfectly, Any idea the alternatives to get mediaStream from peerConnection except getRemoteStreams() and getLocalStreams() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution, getLocalStreams() and getRemoteStreams() function was already deprecated, not all browser still support, safari and mobile browser i.e chrome, safari. So, you can go [here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/webrtcpedia/#getremotestreams-alternative) for the alternatives way to get the local/remote streams.